# Traveling as a 17 year old in Europe

Tags: europe, germany, international-travel, berlin, minors

I have a plan to stay some months in Germany learning about the language and culture. This will all be done in a course at an institute in Berlin, which will be my home for that period of time. But I will have some weeks of and, since this will be my first time in Europe, I would like to visit others parts of the country and do a bit of international travel to France, Denmark and even maybe Italy. Would like to know what kinds of authorizations and documents I would need to do this kind of traveling alone or with another underage companion.

PS: My parents will be a long way away. Back in Brazil, to be more precise.

Comment: @user51110: I guess you meant to say you're "planning" to stay in hotels? "Pretending" means acting as if you do something, but not doing it (I believe it's "fingir" in Portuguese)

Comment: Yes! I'm truly sorry. I am indeed planning to stay in hotels. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: @user51110 Your passport is enough, It lets you stay without a visa for max 3 months in the Schengen area. Remember, the Schengen Area is like a single country, so normally no border controls between Germany and France/Denmark/Italy. Now, because of the migrant crisis, sometimes, at some borders, there will be spot checks on trains and buses (which mean they control some, but not necessairly all people). Even then, your passport will not be stamped

Comment: I've changed the answer a bit, check it out.

Answer (score 6):

> Would like to know what kinds of authorizations and documents I would
>   need to do this kind of traveling...

You'll need only your passport and money.

I'm assuming you're a Brazilian citizen and will thus enjoy visa-free travel in the Schengen area for up to three months.

Please note, though,  that you'll be unable to stay in some hotels, as they sometimes have age limits. But in most cities you'll be able to find a youth hostel or hotel that allows for 17 year old guests. When I was your age I did a fair amount of traveling in Europe, and it's not that hard. But you should definitely check with each establishment regarding your age prior to booking.

I do reccomend that you bring an approval letter from your parents, especially if you might be considering going to Croatia. [More details here.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79497/41775)

I'm not sure if this sort of authorization document would also help you with hotels. So, seek out places that allow minors even without such a letter.

Other than hotels, I can't think of any serious limitations for you as a 17 year old traveling in Europe. (There's not being able to drink alcohol in many places, and being unable to drive cars, obviously, but apart from that.)

Regarding your passport, take very good care of it and keep some copies (photocopies or digital) of it, in case something bad should happen. (Let's hope it doesn't, though.) For the same purpose you might also consider bringing a secondary ID card.

Be careful and have fun!

Comment: @npst you're right. It was changed in 2007. Since I don't smoke and I was already over 18 at that time, I never noticed. But please don't post in German, this is an English-speaking community. :)

Comment: @simbabque Yeah, it's mostly 18 these days. OP mentions Denmark, in which OP will be able to buy beer and wine in shops. However, OP still can't buy liquor or be served in bars in Denmark (until OPs next birthday, that is.)

Comment: I think there are better places to be in Denmark than bars. Places that have less tax. Like the beach or a pølser place or something. :-)

Comment: @simbabque Haha. Yeah. There is much beautiful nature in Denmark, for example.

Comment: I have fond memories of bike rides through needle forests and heath and swamplands and dunes and all. And guf. Do you still have that stuff?

Comment: @simbabque I'm not Danish and haven't been to Denmark since 2009, but yeah, I have those memories too. I'm assuming it's all still there :)