# Solo travelling EU at 17

Tags: paperwork, international-travel, europe, minors

I am from New Zealand and was wondering if anyone has more information about travelling around Europe at 17 solo. The countries I would be visiting are Germany, Switzerland and Italy. Do I need a letter of permission from my parents or any other legal documents, other than a passport?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hitchhiking in Europe under the age of 18](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/hitchhiking-in-europe-under-the-age-of-18)

Comment: A general request for 'more information' is rather broad. If you want to get a good answer, focus on specific aspects. A letter of permission might be useful, but at seventeen expect to travel mostly without anything more than an itinerary and a passport.

Comment: Traveling alone like that is the best adventure you will ever have. Enjoy

Answer (score 10):

It is **advised** that a minor (up to 18) travel with some form of consent from the parents and/or guardians.

Many automobile clubs offer standard forms, most in multiple languages.

- The [Swiss PDF form](https://www.tcs.ch/mam/Digital-Media/PDF/Info-Sheet/reisevollmacht-fuer-minderjaehrige-personen-alleinreisend.pdf) offers all the languages for the area you wish to travel through.

The first page contains information about the minor, the second about the parent/guardian including **ID or passport** number

- a copy of the **ID** of the parents and/or guardians should be attached

Some form of signature verification from a local authority is also advised.

**Note**: Some European countries require a signature authentication by their own Consulate, often using their own forms.

- **under 18**: Cyprus, Finland, Greece, Luxembourg (advised), United Kingdom
- **under 15**: France, [Italy](http://www.poliziadistato.it/statics/31/modulo_dichiarazione_accompagnamento.pdf) , Kosovo, Serbia
- **not required**: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Croatia, Denmark, Estonia, Germany, Hungary, Ireland, Iceland, Latvia, Lithuania, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovenia, Slovakia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland

(based on information found on the German Foreign Office pages as of January 2020)

In Germany (and from the comments probably elsewhere) the signature and copy of the ID of **both** parents are needed (where applicable), otherwise it may not be accepted.

With this consent, booking a Hotel that would otherwise not allow a minor, is then possible in Germany and possibly elsewhere.

---

**Sources**:

- [Documents for minors travelling in the EU. Rules and authorisations needed - Your Europe](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/travel-documents-minors/index_en.htm)

  - [Documents for minors travelling in the EU - Germany](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/travel-documents-minors/germany/index_en.htm)

    - [Einverständniserklärung für Minderjährige (in German)](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/11-kindohneeltern/606308)
    - [PDF Form: Letter of consent to minors without parent (German and English)](https://res.cloudinary.com/adacde/image/upload/v1571649306/ADAC-eV/KOR/Text/PDF/reisevollmacht-englisch_kutovt.pdf)
  - [Documents for minors travelling in the EU - Italy](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/travel-documents-minors/italy/index_en.htm)

    - [PDF Form: Letter of consent to minors under age 14](http://www.poliziadistato.it/statics/31/modulo_dichiarazione_accompagnamento.pdf)
  - [Reisen mit Minderjährigen - TCS Schweiz (in German)](https://www.tcs.ch/de/camping-reisen/reiseinformationen/wissenswertes/reisetipps/reisen-mit-minderjaehrigen.php)

    - [PDF Form: Letter of consent to minors without parent (German, French, Italian and English)](https://www.tcs.ch/mam/Digital-Media/PDF/Info-Sheet/reisevollmacht-fuer-minderjaehrige-personen-alleinreisend.pdf)

Comment: It would be a good idea to have the agreement of **all** legal guardians, not just one, and also to mention explicitly if the minor travels with others (minor or adult).

Comment: @o.m. any particular reason for the first part (agreement of all legal guardians)?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén, agreement by one but not all parents may be part of a custody dispute/abduction. They advise getting the agreement of any absent guardians even if one guardian is present.

Comment: @o.m. But any Border Control or Hotel reading it will not know of any custody conditions. A single parent won't need to get a second signature. The forms offered allow one or both. There are also forms for one Spouse accompaning the child with the other signing.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, it's true that Border Control won't know of any custody conditions. Risk to the traveler, however, is that because of age or gender, Border Control might see especially travel accompanied by only one parent as an attempted end-run around a custody arrangement or decree, and refuse permission to board or to cross the border. The issue of solo or accompanied-by-one parent travel is to carry the written permission of all non-present parents.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica, o. m. I have adapted the answer after finding confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

As an under 18 you will not be allowed in some or even most hotels and hostels may have additional requirements.
The stories do differ, some young people report no problems at all, others report not being able to find hotels at all.

The additional requirements hostels seem to ask, when they do want them, is a letter of permission from your parents. The letter, mentioned in the answer by @Mark Johnson, will likely do for that. But if not mentioned, your parents may write a separate letter, just in English and/or German, would likely do.

If you can postpone your travel till you are 18 you will not have any problem with hostels or hotels.

It is not likely the people at the border will ask you for your letter of permissions, but you will feel more confident when you have it and that will show in your behavior and stance. Have proof of enough money (your bank card and a recent bank statement and if possible a credit card) in your hand luggage. If your parents are going to top up your bank account, having a letter of them with their promise is very handy to have.)

The biggest risk for young people traveling alone is that when things go wrong, they do not have the experience to handle it. And that experience does not only come with years but also with travel. If you have not (yet) traveled alone in your home country, you may want to do that instead or before coming to Europe. This is not legal but sensible advice.

Traveling with a commercial company or a group of people you know before setting out would be a better option than traveling alone.
Traveling with people you meet on the way or worse, you find online just for the reason of traveling together, has risks, especially if you trust each other with your money and passports. If you do end up traveling with people like that keep your own passport and only put a small amount of money in a common purse or pay your part each time or pay in turn and keep check you do not pay more or less than the other(s) so no bad things come from that.

Traveling alone can be lonely, be prepared for that and aware that it will become a problem.

It can be a good adventure. It can also turn into the worst nightmare you ever heard about. Be careful, even when a country is safe, it does not follow that all tourists in it are safe.
And trusting in people you meet while traveling can bring the nightmare about.

Comment: Becoming a member of a Youth hostel, which is widely supported in Germany, Switzerland and Italy,  is also a good idea.  [YHA New Zealand is part of Hostelling International](https://www.yha.co.nz/hostels/hostelling-international)

Comment: Being a member does not change the age requirements. And there are many other hostels that are not part of the HI network.

Comment: Anyone over the age of 16 can stay in a Youth Hostel, that is what they are for.

Comment: Not in every country without parental consent, as far as I know. And even with parental consent it has been reported (and I can not find that link anymore) that hostels in some countries do not accept under 18 travelers when traveling alone.

Comment: In all 3 countries (confirmed) and in general 14-18 can stay in youth hostels. Some require written consent in the form asked here. As stated, this is what the origination is for.

Comment: Forgot to add 'in Europe' to the previous first sentence. You also must be a member from your  own country (allthough in the past a visitor's membership could be applied for)

Comment: Of course, one could always travel with a 18+ year old friend and have them do the check-in :)

Comment: Traveling alone at 17 is lonely in the sense that a supermodel at a nightclub is lonely.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote here just because factually: (1) there is absolutely, utterly, no problem staying at Youth Hostels, in the 3 countries mentioned.  (2) In (say) the US it's true that generally, 99% of the time, <18s cannot check in to a hotel.  But in the 3 countries mentioned, only in "very few" (say, 10-20% of cases) can an <18 not check in to a hotel.

Comment: (actually I didn't downvote, because I rarely do so on principle, heh :) )

Comment: Having traveled alone as a young woman, (if a bit over 18 at the time) I know that you can be very lonely, and your other claims sound as false to me.

Comment: @Willeke I can't say how it is today, but in the 1970's it was common place. I never had any problems. The Youth Hostels made it possible to meet others of the same age and interests.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, it also depends on the person themselves, but even when you do meet fantastic travel companions in some of the hostels, you can not be sure you meet them in all. Many HI hostels now mostly cater to groups (like schools), which makes them less suitable for people traveling alone.