# Hosting foreign minors in Switzerland and Italy

Tags: schengen, italy, switzerland, minors

We are planning on hosting a group of British minors (15 years old) in Switzerland this spring. They will be flying alone to Italy where we will pick them up at the airport and drive them across the border to our home in Switzerland (and visit several places in both countries during their stay).

I'm failing to find any online resources that clearly state what are the legal requirements for this in those countries.

In case it make any difference, this are family friends; we know well both the children and their parents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Italy, this is no problem for the ages 15 to 17 (inclusive)

- up to 14 (inclusive) a form is needed that must be varified by an Italian Consulate

For both (Italy and Switzerland) is is advised to get a written consent from the parents which should include your name and address being visited.
Theoretically this could also be asked for when leaving the United Kindom.

The link below contains a link to a Swiss form that should serve your purpose well since the field descriptions are listed in all needed languages.

All parents must sign it and a copy of a Photo ID (Driver's Licence) should be included.

---

**Sources**:

- [paperwork - Solo travelling EU at 17](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/151773/95267)